# issue in downloading and saving audio file in didSelectRowAt func

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an application that downloads audio file from the server, save it in the device and then tap again to play it, but the problem is that every time i tap on the cell the file re-downloaded !!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedCellIndex = indexPath
    
    let cell = self.audioTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AudioTableViewCell
    let audioUrl = audio[indexPath.row].audioUrl
    configure(with: audioUrl, indexPath: indexPath, cell: cell)
}


func configure(with myUrl : String, indexPath: IndexPath, cell: AudioTableViewCell) {
    downloadAndSaveAudioFile(urlString: myUrl, index: indexPath, cell: cell)
}

func downloadAndSaveAudioFile(urlString: String, index: IndexPath, cell: AudioTableViewCell) {
    guard let audioUrl = URL(string: urlString) else {return}

    let documentsDirectoryURL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    let destinationUrl = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(audioUrl.lastPathComponent)
    
    // every time i tapped the cell, validation of this condition fails

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationUrl.path) { 
        print("The file already exists at path")
    } else {
        
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
        let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: audioUrl)
        downloadTask.resume()
        
    }
    
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
    let percentege = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.myProg = percentege * 100
                let cell = self.audioTableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedCellIndex!) as! AudioTableViewCell
                cell.progressV.progress = percentege
            }
    
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didResumeAtOffset fileOffset: Int64, expectedTotalBytes: Int64) {

    print("\(expectedTotalBytes)")
}


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("did finish downloading To...")
    
    let cell = self.audioTableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedCellIndex!) as! AudioTableViewCell
    cell.img.image = UIImage(systemName: "play.fill")
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    print("completed: error: \(String(describing: error))")
}
```

Is there any advice or explanation of the method?

Comment: Where is the code to save the audio file in the documents folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't move your downloaded file to the `destination path` yet. So that's why the check `fileExists` always failed.

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    print("did finish downloading To...")
    
    let cell = self.audioTableView.cellForRow(at: self.selectedCellIndex!) as! AudioTableViewCell
    cell.img.image = UIImage(systemName: "play.fill")
    
    // After downloading your file, you need to move it to your destination url
    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: `your new destination`)
        print("File moved to documents folder")
    } catch {
        print("Error when moving file")
    }

}
```

Here is an example: https://mobikul.com/play-audio-file-save-document-directory-ios-swift/

Comment: thank you its work and I use DispatchQueue.main.async for updating ui

Comment: Oh you're right, I forgot about the UI updates above. Nice catch.